# IE 8 javascript modernizer

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript

My customer uses IE 8 which doesn´t have several array methods that newer browsers have. The application have to work in others browsers too (chrome and FF).

In order to be able to program with those array methods in IE 8, I included the 'Array prototype extensions' library (part of the [js-methods project](https://code.google.com/p/js-methods/)) which works perfectly for us.

Given I really don´t know all the differences between the IE 8 javascript version and the IE 9/10 version, I would like to know if i have better options. I mean, other libraries to 'upgrade' the javascript.

Comment: [You ain't gonna need it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: I understand your point. The question is because we develop with chrome and don´t want the user find defects because of the differences in the javascript version.

Comment: jQuery provides some insulation between browser versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the way you're doing it now. This is exactly what the [js-methods](https://code.google.com/p/js-methods/) project was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the Array methods, then you chose wisely. If you need something more powerful, look at jquery or ExtJs.